# Bash Using variable names in sed to insert record

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed in bash shell to insert a new row before row 1 with : as the Field Separator into an existing file but when I do it, it's printing the variable names instead of the values.  Here's what I have.  Sed seems to have quirky issues with variable names.  Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash
select CHOICE in add remove list find exit
do
echo "Pick a directory option: "
 case $CHOICE in
  add)
   printf "What is the first name? "
    read first
   printf "What is the last name? "
    read last
   printf "What is the street address? "
    read address
   printf "What is the city? "
    read city 
   printf "What is the State abreviation? "
    read state
   printf "What is the zip code? "
    read zip
   printf "What is the phone number? "
    read phone
   cat listing.txt | sed '1 i\ > "$first" ":" "$last" ":" "$address" ":" "$city" ":" "$state" ":" "$zip" ":" "$phone"' listing.txt;;
 esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to edit listing.txt in place?  Instead of the line starting `cat listing.txt...`, use this:

```
sed -i.bak "
1 i\\
$first : $last : $address : $city : $state : $zip : $phone
" listing.txt
```

This assumes that you didn't actually want quotes in the listing.txt file.  It will also leave a listing.txt.bak as a backup to the edited file.